# Searching for book about Finnish girl in 19th century who migrates to Norway

Tags: identification-request

15 years ago I read a great book that I have searched for online and at Nordic stores and come up a-cropper.  It's set in the 19th c (I think) and follows the story of a poor Finnish girl who migrates to Norway (but it could be Sweden) and faces a lot of discrimination because of being Finn. As I remember she works various jobs and definitely moves around a bit.  I think she ends up in a coastal town in Norway or Sweden. Wish I remembered more.  Don't remember a lot of romance, it's more about her struggles and triumphs.  Any hints welcome.  My daughter is studying Finnish and Swedish and is really interested in reading it!

Comment: Do you recall what language the book was written in? If you remember any character names too, that would be very useful.

Comment: Thanks, I read it in English but it might have been translated from Finnish.  I don't remember any names!